# Downgrade Perl 5.16 to 5.14

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, yum, perl

I carelessly did `yum update` on my Amazon Linux AMI and updated Perl. Now my Movable Type install doesn't work. I did some google but could not find any solution except downgrading Perl to 5.14. Current version of the Perl is 5.16.3

Here is the error log for the Movable Type.

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/FCGI/FCGI.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
defined(@array) is deprecated at /var/www/html/mt/extlib/CGI.pm line 527.
(Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
```

I am not a Perl wiz but there where some dependencies issues? so rewriting the CGI.pm file is not a option.

I tried 
`yum downgrade perl` but I receive dependencies error.

Answer (score 1):

Your FCGI module is compiled against Perl 5.14. Reinstall it with `cpan -f -i FCGI`.